# Do the JavaScript web APIs run on a different thread than the call stack thread?

Tags: javascript

At 12:16 in the following video by Philip Roberts, he talks about the Web APIs and Node APIs running on different threads than the call stack, if I am understanding him correctly? So, is this correct, do the Web APIs and Node APIs run on different threads than the call stack and event loop?

If true, does this mean that they will run in parallel to JavaScript being executed in the call stack?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ

Comment: Sort of, but the effective result is NO. What he said is that "the run time can only do one thing at a time". He then repeats this several times. The Web APIs and Node APIs (this is V8 specific) run in separate threads; but, when interacting with the runtime, they must inject themselves into the stack (or event loop) within the single thread of the runtime. Meaning, all those tasks are _effectively_ running in the one thread that the run time is limited to.

Comment: He does state that the "the run time can only do one thing at a time" but then states that the Web APIs "are effectively threads that you cant access like threads you can just like make calls to..." then, clearly shows `setTimeout` taking place within the Web API and when completed, the Web API pushing the result into the event loop, which then gets pushed into the call stack. I've watched this video multiple times and my interpretation is when `setTimeout` for example is called, it's executed in the Web API and then the result pushed in the event loop, no different than an API request...

Comment: Yes, your interpretation is correct. The browser optimizes performance in a Muti-threaded way, but your JS app is still constrained. So the effective overall result is still constrained by the path of most resistance - the single thread of the JS runtime.  Unless you use WebWorkers :-)

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying, you're saying that even though the Web API or Node API is doing some work in parallel on a different thread, a JS app is still constrained by the fact that the result of that work, ends up in the event loop, which then pushes the result into the call stack, when the call stack is finished doing the work that is currently in it? Nothing can happen until the call stack is empty.

Comment: Yes....Exactly!

Comment: Thank you. It makes perfect sense to me now!

Comment: I Would like to add and make corrections here. Web api (like setTimeout) does NOT execute the code. At 14:40, he clearly says, it is executed when it gets into stack.

The JS engine is responsible for executing js code. Web apis are just async operations which includes - an event and a callback after that event. So, when that event occurs or finished, then the callback is sent to queue. Event loop, sends this callback method to call stack and then it is executed by js engine.

Comment: @Piyush settimeout's execution would involve waiting for a period of time and that does not happen on the stack. Watching that video  it happens in the webapi, then after the time has elapsed, then the settimeout is done(executed in a sense, and for the duration that you specified), and the function that was passed to settimeout, goes to the task queue and the event loop puts it onto the stack when the stack is empty. And the function executes. So there is execution in the webapi stage in terms of waiting. And that is executing (some of) your code 'cos you specified a settimeout and a duration

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Short Answer: Yes.

As has been pointed out in the comments, Web APIs "are effectively threads" although with a different behavior and purpose.

And, finally, the result will still be accessed and limited by the single "threadedness" of the JavaScript runtime when whichever callback is pushed into the Call Stack.

Comment: You mean setimeout and setiinterval also run on different thread ? And each of them has different call stack as a thread has its own stack, isn't ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the execution of the web-API happens in parallel in another thread and when the execution is complete, the result(or callback) is pushed onto the task queue, and when there's nothing on the call-stack, the event loop picks this result(or callback) from task queue and puts it on the call-stack.

The execution of the web-API code itself happens on a separate thread but the code that works with the result executes on the call-stack.

Comment: Hi, while your answer may be good, it's better to add facts and citations, or links to documentation. Please read [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  Thank you